# Problems with SetBool() unity5 (javascript)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been doing research and I found some code to set a boolean parameter to true. I looked in the Unity API and this code should work(but it doesn't):

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
var animator = Animator;
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("W") || Input.GetKeyDown("s")){

        animator.SetBool("please", true);
    }
    else{

        animator.SetBool("please", false);
}
}
```

Do any of you have any idea what is happening? I keep getting the error: 'SetBool' is not a member of System.type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to retrieve the Animator component attached to your gameobject first. You were doing it wrong. Also, it's a good practice to use the hash of the bool parameter instead of its name, see below.

```
var animator : Animator ;
var boolHash : int;

function Start () {
    animator = GetComponent(Animator) as Animator;
    boolHash = Animator.StringToHash("please") ;
}

function Update ()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("W") || Input.GetKeyDown("s"))
    {
        animator.SetBool(boolHash, true);
    }   
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool(boolHash, false);
    }
}
```